# convert data with LabelEncoder

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, label-encoding

I wrote this function to convert categorical features with LabelEncoder

```
#convert columns to dummies with LabelEncoder
cols = ['ToolType', 'TestType', 'BatteryType']
#apply ene hot encoder
le = LabelEncoder()
for col in cols:
    data[col] = data[col].astype('|S') #convert object to str type before apply label encoder
    le.fit(ravel(data[col]))
    data[col] = le.transform(ravel(data[col]))
```

There are null values in those columns, but there is an error like this

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Does anyone know how to help me to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is converting to numpy `bytes_` which the encoder does not support:

```py
data[col] = data[col].astype('|S')
```

If you want to convert to string, change `'|S'` to `str`:

```py
data[col] = data[col].astype(str)
```

---

As a side note, you can cut the loop down to one line with [**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [**`fit_transform`**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.fit_transform):

```py
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(le.fit_transform)
```